# How to refresh different page if a button was clicked in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html

So i have this form where the admin update all the products info and prices and whenever he click save it button, i want that different page who display all product to be refreshed so that it  will update the changes. Which the client will see an updated info and they don't have to manually refresh it. i just want to try something different

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  window["http://127.0.0.1:5000/thisdifferentpage"].reload(true);
});
```

```html
<a href='#' id="button">Refresh the thisdifferentpage</a>
```

it doesn't work,

Comment: Hi Phil, maybe instead of refreshing the page you could consider using AJAX to update the information you need?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve], this website is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button will refresh the page:

```
<button id="refresh-button" onclick="reload()">Refresh page</button>
```

Comment: yes it will refresh the current page of where that button is, but what i want is that it will reload the different location for example if he click that button.

Comment: You can't, but you can open that page and then refresh it if you want it.

Comment: uhm, yes, but it seems like there's no such thing that i can refresh different page if i click that button. because i want that client who's in that view.html to get refreshed if the admin click the button from its admin.html page

Comment: You can't do that in pure JavaScript, you'll need a server-side language like NodeJS or PHP.

Comment: Im just trying new ways. So i actually need a server language/script to do that, uhm guess it's finish. tnx